# What are auto executable jars?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was going through spring-boot-maven-plugin documentation and came across a term auto executable jar.

Could someone please explain me what is an auto executable jar and how is it different then normal jar files and how they are auto executed?

spring-boot-maven-plugin documentation mentions the term but does not go further to explain it

repackage: create a jar or war file that is auto-executable. It can replace the regular artifact or can be attached to the build lifecycle with a separate classifier.

Comment: Never heard about auto executable jars.

Answer (score 2):

```
Could someone please explain me what is an auto executable jar
```

> A fully executable jar can be executed like any other executable
>   binary or it can be registered with init.d or systemd. This makes it
>   very easy to install and manage Spring Boot applications in common
>   production environments.

So In conclusion is like any other executable when you use a executable jar

```
how is it different then normal jar files and how they are auto executed?
```

Well a java file you need to run with  `java -jar`

[From Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html)

Comment: This seems to be correct, but it begs the question of how the result is achieved.  In particular, is an autoexecutable jar still a normal jar that can be examined, unpacked, and maybe even modified via the `jar` tool?

Comment: The answer seems to be "Fully executable jars work by embedding an extra script at the front of the file," which makes sense.  However, "Currently, some tools do not accept this format, so you may not always be able to use this technique. For example, `jar -xf` may silently fail to extract a jar or war that has been made fully executable," which I suspect in fact understates the issue.  It appears to me that an "autoexecutable jar" is not a jar in the ordinary sense at all.

Comment: A fully executable jar is different than an executable jar that you can run via `java -jar` command.
It is made for running in production environments like linux with `./my-jar.jar` or windows when executing a .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven build of a Springboot application first build your own application and pack it into a JAR file.

In the second stage (repackage) it will wrap that jar with all the jar files from the dependency tree into a new *wrapper* jar archive. It will also generate a Manifest file where is defined what's the application Main class is (also in the *wrapper* jar).

After mvn package you can also see 2 jar files in your target directory. The original file and the *wrapped* jar file.

You can start a Springboot application with a simple command like:

```
java -jar my-springboot-app.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest that auto executable means that you supplied main method so that it can be launched with java -jar options, otherwise it may be just a java library.
Here is a quote from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html

Repackages existing JAR and WAR archives so that they can be executed from the command line using java -jar. With layout=NONE can also be used simply to package a JAR with nested dependencies (and no main class, so not executable).

Answer (score 0):

- Executable jar - the one that has main class declared in manifest and can be run with `java -jar yourJarFile.jar` command
- Other jars - jars jars without delcared main calss. Can be anything - application, library, etc. Still can run application by providing fully.qualified.class.name as entry point like `java -cp yourJarFile.jar my.bootstrap.BootstrapClass`
- Autoexecutable jars - never heard about it :)